# Using Uniform convergence and Integration to find the Limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals, uniform-convergence

So I have to work out $\lim_{n \to \infty} \ \int^2_0 \left(e^x+e^{\frac{x^2}{n}}\right) dx$.

First we will check if the integrand converges normally, we have $x \to x$ as $n \to \infty$ and also $\frac{x^2}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, so we then have:

$$e^x + e^\frac{x^2}{n} \to e^x+1 \text{ as } n \to \infty.$$

We can test the convergence of this on our bounds $[0,2]$ by: $$\left|(e^x + e^\frac{x^2}{n}) - (e^x+1)\right| = \left|e^\frac{x^2}{n}-1\right|= \sup_{x \ \epsilon 
\ [0,2]}\left|e^\frac{x^2}{n}-1\right|≤ \left|e^\frac{4}{n}-1\right| \to 0$$

Which means it does in fact converge uniformly, so for every n the function $e^x+e^\frac{x^2}{n}$ is integrable so we can apply: $$ \int_a^b f = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b f_n $$

This is where I am stuck, I either don't know where to go from here or I have already made a mistake... Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused. It seems like you already did all of the hard work. You just have to integrate $f(x)=e^x + 1 .$

Comment: @zugzug My apologies, my main problem was that I was doubting I had done it right, if I simply just nee to continue with my integration then that clears things up substantially :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x) = e^x + e^4$ on $[0,2]$. Then $$f_n(x) = e^x + e^{\frac{x^2}n}\leqslant e^x+e^4=g(x)$$ for all $x\in[0,2]$, and $$\int_0^2 |g(x)|\ \mathsf dx = \int_0^2\left(e^x+e^4\right)\ \mathsf dx = 2e^4 + e^2 - 1<\infty.  $$ It follows from the dominated convergence theorem that
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^2 f_n(x)\ \mathsf dx &= \int_0^2 \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)\ \mathsf dx\\ &= \int_0^2 (e^x+1)\ \mathsf dx\\ &= e^2 + 1.
\end{align}